# Unclickable in IE 6

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

It is all my html code write in  XSL file.
Div body I have a div categories with two area left and right
In each side I have the same div contain a link, but the link in the right can click able and in the left unclickable. Someone have the same issue show me the way please!!

```
<xsl:for-each select="categories/category">
<div class="Categories-News">
<div class="Categories-News-Title">
<a href="/{@name}">
<xsl:value-of select="@label" />
</a>
</div>
<div class="Categories-News-Left">
<div class="Categories-Top-News">
<div class="Categories-Top-Wrap-Content">
<xsl:if test="article[1]/@image">
<div class="Wrap-Border">
<div class="Wrap-Image">
<img src="{article[1]/@image}-140x120.jpg" width="121" />
</div>
</div>
</xsl:if>
<p class="categories-title">
<a href="{article[1]/@seo-url}">
<xsl:value-of select="article[1]/@title"
disable-output-escaping="yes" />
</a>
</p>
<p>
<a href="{article[1]/@url}" class="edi">
<xsl:value-of select="article[1]/@edition" />
</a>
-
<xsl:value-of select="formater:date(article[1]/@date)" />
</p>
<xsl:value-of select="article[1]/@body"
disable-output-escaping="yes" />
</div>
</div>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="article[1]/related">
<xsl:for-each select="article[1]/related">
<div class="Relate-Items">
<div class="arrow"></div>
<div class="Linklink">
<a href="{@seo-url}">
<xsl:value-of select="@title"                                                   disable-output-escaping="yes" />
</a>
<span>
<a href="{@url}" class="edition">
<xsl:value-of select="@edition" />
</a>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:for-each select="article">
<xsl:if test="position() &lt; 5 and position() &gt; 1">
<div class="Relate-Items">
<div class="arrow"></div>
<div class="Linklink">
<a href="{@seo-url}">
<xsl:value-of select="@title"
disable-output-escaping="yes" />
</a>
<span>
<a href="{@url}" class="edition">
<xsl:value-of select="@edition" />
</a>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</div>
<div class="Categories-News-Right">
<xsl:for-each select="article[position() &gt; 4]">
<div class="Relate-Items">
<div class="arrow"></div>
<div class="Linklink">
<a href="{@seo-url}">
<xsl:value-of select="@title" />
</a>
<span>
<a href="{@url}" class="edition">
<xsl:value-of select="@edition" />
</a>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</xsl:for-each>
</div>
</div>
</xsl:for-each>
```

And I saw that when this page loading in IE 6 I still can click on the link in the left but when its finished load the page I can't click on the link

Comment: please show us your html + css

Comment: The css classes don't match the html ones, there's no header html and there's no z-indexes. We can't help you without accurate data.

Comment: I'm so sorry to waste your time annakata, this all my html code and css I don't know this is enought, isn't it? Anyway thank you for your attention my problem!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar behaviour recently. The problem was that I had a div-element with fixed height/width, but the content got larger than "calculated". So everything outside the specified dimensions was shown, but not clickable. So try to enlarge the div size if specified.